# Как разбить элемент списка на несколько эелементов? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, кортежи, psutil

суть такая - создаю список steampidinfo

```
import psutil
steampidinfo = [item for item in psutil.process_iter() if item.name() == 'steam.exe']
```

в списке хранится вся информация по имени процесса в таком виде:

```
[psutil.Process(pid=4004, name='steam.exe', status='running', started='22:04:57'), psutil.Process(pid=25156, name='steam.exe', status='running', started='22:04:58')]
```

как правильно разбить список до только нужной мне информации?
я хочу хранить информацию о pid процесса и started для их сравнивания между собой в отдельной переменной, примерно так:

```
steam1 = (pid = 4004), (started='22:04:57')
steam2 = (pid = 25156), (started='22:04:58')
```

что бы после по хранящимся pid взаимодействовать с определенным окном, а по started сравнивать какое когда открылось
уверен вопрос решается достаточно просто, но до ответа все никак не могу добраться.

Comment: циклы проходили?

Comment: моя проблема в том что 
[psutil.Process(pid=4004, name='steam.exe', status='running', started='22:04:57'),psutil.Process(pid=25156, name='steam.exe', status='running', started='22:04:58')] это только 2 элемента списка, а как преобразовать каждый элемент хотя бы в отдельный список с параметрами pid, name, status, started я понять не могу :( , а так да, конечно проходили) видимо самого познания языка не хватает, поэтому и не могу справиться.

Comment: Не очень понятно, в чём конкретно у вас проблема. К элементам списка можно обращаться по индексу или перебирать их в цикле - в отдельные переменные раскладывать их смысла нет. Информация о pid и started в элементах вашего списка есть. Что именно у вас не получается? Приведите чёткий пример, какую задачу вы не можете решить на основе того списка, который у вас уже есть.

Comment: [[item.pid, item.create_time()] for item in psutil.process_iter() if item.name() == 'steam.exe']

Comment: @СергейШ Спасибо! это то что мне было нужно, оказалось достаточно просто, дальше от этого буду скакать!

Comment: Можно не только список списков, а так же спискок словарей или кортежей

Comment: Это все мне еще предстоит изучить, лучше не буду с этим торопиться)